# QueryDsl parse JsonArray into JsonObject before updating Json column

Tags: mysql, querydsl

I'm now using MySQL 5.7.35 version.

I added `implementation("com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:1.0.0")` into gradle,
and set entity field 'data' into type 'JsonArray'.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "json_data")
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JsonData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private JSONArray data;
}
```

```java
    @Transactional
    public void updateJsonData() throws ParseException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        log.info("jsonArray: " + jsonArray);

        primaryQueryFactory.update(jsonData)
                .set(jsonData.labelData, jsonArray)
                .where(jsonData.jsonDataNo.eq(1))
                .execute();

        String data = "[{\"h\": 0.1, \"w\": 0.1, \"x\": 0.1, \"y\": 0.1}]";
        jsonArray = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(data);
        log.info("jsonArray: " + jsonArray);

        primaryQueryFactory.update(jsonData)
                .set(jsonData.labelData, jsonArray)
                .where(jsonData.jsonDataNo.eq(1))
                .execute();
    }
```

When I executed updateJsonData() function and printed log, it showed

```
2022-01-13 13:23:09.433 INFO  [c.v.a.d.m.r.JsonDataRepositorySupport:87] : jsonArray: [] 
Hibernate: 
    update
        vt_project_json_data 
    set
        label_data=null 
    where
        json_data_no=?
2022-01-13 13:23:09.544 TRACE [o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:64] : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1] 


2022-01-13 13:23:09.552 INFO  [c.v.a.d.m.r.JsonDataRepositorySupport:96] : jsonArray: [{"w":0.1,"h":0.1,"x":0.1,"y":0.1}] 
Hibernate: 
    update
        vt_project_json_data 
    set
        label_data=? 
    where
        json_data_no=?
2022-01-13 13:23:09.554 TRACE [o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:64] : binding parameter [1] as [OTHER] - [{"w":0.1,"h":0.1,"x":0.1,"y":0.1}] 
2022-01-13 13:23:09.571 TRACE [o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:64] : binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [1]
```

If JsonArray is empty, querydsl updates column as `null`.
If not, querydsl updates column as `JsonArray`, but in MySQL, it is saved as `JsonObject`.

When I updated columns by using JPA, it worked properly.
But Querydsl doesn't work properly.
How can I make it right?

Comment: *If not, querydsl updates column as JsonArray, but in MySQL, it is saved as JsonObject.* Enable General Query Log and look what SQL text is received by MySQL server. It is possible that your client assumes JSON array as array of values which must be provided to MySQL in batch mode, and iterates the insertion over the elements of this array. Test - use `[[{"w":0.1,"h":0.1,"x":0.1,"y":0.1}]]`.

Comment: I enabled general query log and found that JsonArray was inserted as JsonObject.
As you said, it seems like JsonArray was provided to MySQL in batch mode.
When I tested using `[{"w":0.1,"h":0.1,"x":0.1,"y":0.1}, {"w":0.2,"h":0.2,"x":0.2,"y":0.2}]`,
application log showed `update json_data set label_data=(? ,?)` 
and the values were `[{"w":0.1,"h":0.1,"x":0.1,"y":0.1}]` and `[{"w":0.2,"h":0.2,"x":0.2,"y":0.2}]`.

By adding my JsonArray into new JsonArray, problem was solved.
I wonder how MySQL handle JsonArray in this way.
Can you give me an advice what to look for?

Comment: *I wonder how MySQL handle JsonArray in this way.* This is querydsl who "un-arrayed" provided data. Not MySQL.

Comment: Oh, I see! You helped me a lot. I appreciate it!! Thank you!!